# How to subset a network graph keeping the top n components?

Tags: r, networking, igraph

I have a disconnected network with many small components. 
I would like to keep only those components are above the 75th percentile in size.
In using decompose a list of network is produced that cannot be plotted as one.

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(123)
g <- erdos.renyi.game(100, 0.02, directed = FALSE, loops = TRUE)

components(g)$csize
components <- which(components(g)$csize>=quantile(components(g)$csize,.75))
g_final <- igraph::decompose(g, max.comps =  length(components), min.vertices = 2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what you really want to use is `induced_subgraph`.

I really dislike that you used the name of the function components as the name of a variable,  so I have changed it here to Components.

```
Components <- which(components(g)$csize>=quantile(components(g)$csize,.75))
BigComp <-induced_subgraph(g, 
            which(components(g)$membership %in% Components))
plot(BigComp)
```

[image: Subgraph of large components]